# Run VBA code and keep Excels UNDO/REDO intact?

Tags: vba, excel

I run this code to force update a few charts:

```
'Force update charts
For Each cht In Sheets("Charts").ChartObjects
    cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.Add Source:=Worksheets("Builder").Range("AI2:AI7")
    cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(cht.Chart.SeriesCollection.Count).Delete
Next cht
```

I never want to undo or redo the lines below from the Excel quick access bar. Unfortunately the  lines above clear Excels undo/redo list and I can no longer undo/redo changes.

Is it possible to make Excels undo/redo ignore the VBA code that runs and not be cleared?

Answer (score 4):

> Is it possible to make Excels undo/redo ignore the VBA code

NO

> ... and not be cleared?

YES

Whatever action that you perform in Excel Spreadsheet is stored in a list which is called the Undo List. So when you do an Undo for the first time, Excel refers to this list and then Undoes the last action that you performed.

For example, the below will give you the last action performed.

```
Debug.Print Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)
```

You might want to see this link on [Creating An Undo Handler To Undo Changes Done By Excel VBA](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA00.asp) by Jan Karel Pieterse.